# Getting errors while >> sudo npm install -g onoff in raspbian OS

Tags: installation, raspberry-pi, node.js

error :

> epoll@2.0.7 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/onoff/node_modules/epoll
> node-gyp rebuild
>
> gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.node-gyp/10.15.0"
> gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/onoff/node_modules/epoll/.node-gyp"
> gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
> gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
> gyp ERR! configure error
> gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/onoff/node_modules/epoll/.node-gyp'
> gyp ERR! System Linux 4.14.79-v7+
> gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
> gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/onoff/node_modules/epoll
> gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.0
> gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
> gyp ERR! not ok
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! epoll@2.0.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the epoll@2.0.7 install script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-01-16T03_11_50_846Z-debug.log